# Remove-Method in Java doesn't work properly

Tags: java, avl-tree, removechild

I just want you to have a quick look on my AVL-Tree, which I'm programming. I wrote an AVL-Tree and therefore a remove-Method. The problem with this method is that, the other child of the parent of the node (read it please again, sorry that this sounds a bit complicated) which I'm removing, doesn't get printed out, so also gets removed and I dont know why. Here the code:

```
@Override
public void remove(E value) throws NoSuchElementException {
    if(!contains(value)) throw new NoSuchElementException("Doesn't exist!");
    else{
        root = remove(finds(value).value, root);
    }
}

private Node remove(E x, Node t){


     if (t==null)    {
          System.out.println("Sorry but you're mistaken, " + t + " doesn't exist in this tree :)\n");
          return null;
      }
      System.out.println("Remove starts... " + t.value + " and " + x);

      if (x.compareTo(t.value) < 0 ) {
          t.left = remove(x,t.left);



      }
      else if (x.compareTo(t.value) > 0) {
          t.right = remove(x,t.right);


      }

      else if(t.left != null) {
          t.value = biggest(t.left).value;
          remove(t.value, t.left);


      }

      else
          t = (t.left != null) ? t.left : t.right;


      return t;
}

AuDTree<Integer> a = new AuDTree<Integer>();
    a.insert(7);
    a.insert(5);
    a.insert(9);
    a.insert(4);
    a.insert(6);
    a.insert(10);
    a.insert(8);
    a.remove(4);
```

this is the test. When I remove the "4", the "6" also gets removed. When I remove the "8", the "10" gets removed, and so on. The AVL-Tree looks like this:

```
                                7
                           5        9
                        4     6  8    10
```

Thank you in beforehand :)

Comment: would be better if you wrote `sibling` instead ;)

Comment: Aaah, sounds better. The chief thing is you understand it :D

Comment: `else if(t.left != null)` doesn't make sense because the condition has nothing to do with the previous conditions  of comparing the value of `x`. So that statement won't ever be entered and the `else` statement will be entered if `x == t.value`

Comment: Sadly nobody has answered, but I managed it by myself. Still thank you :)